# QSettings setpath ini format still using registry on windows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qsettings

I'm trying to set the path to store some custom settings for my app using QSettings::setPath and defaulFormat but both seem to be ignored when I try and use the settings file.

```
>>> QSettings.setDefaultFormat(QSettings.IniFormat)
>>> QSettings.setPath(QSettings.IniFormat, QSettings.UserScope, "C:\\")
>>> settings3 = QSettings("Balh", "MyApp")
>>> settings3.fileName()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Balh\\MyApp')
```

I would like to stay using `settings = QSettings()` if I can without having to supply `QSettings::IniFormat` to it as it is a cross platform app and should use the native format if the custom path isn't set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The QSettings documentation misleadingly suggests that the code

```
QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Facturo-Pro");
```

is equivalent to

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Moose Soft");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Facturo-Pro");
QSettings settings;
```

but this is not true.  Try this

```
from PySide import QtCore
QtCore.QSettings.setDefaultFormat(QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

settings = QtCore.QSettings("Moose Soft", "Facturo-Pro")
print settings.format()

QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("MooseSoft")
QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("Facturo-Pro")
settings = QtCore.QSettings()
print settings.format()
```

and you will see that only the second constructor uses the default format.  And if you look at the QSettings constructor documentation you will see this confirmed:

> Example:
>
> ```
> QSettings settings("Moose Tech", "Facturo-Pro");
> ```
>
> The scope is set to QSettings::UserScope, and the format is set to
>   QSettings.NativeFormat (i.e. calling setDefaultFormat() before calling this constructor
>   has no effect).

Only some of the QSettings constructors honour the default format and you have chosen one that doesn't.